# "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[Any]'" - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, types, double, option-type

I am learning Swift, and I'm currently building a small application which stores an array of doubles into NsUserDefaults, and then retrieves the values. I would then like to perform some maths on the data, and output the result as a string, however, type restrictions mean that I'm not able to do so.

**Currently my code is as follows:**

```
 // SAVE DOUBLES TO NSUSERDEFAULTS
 let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
 let distanceElapsed=0.0
 let counter=3.0
 let paceVal=5.4
 let genericValues=[Double(distanceElapsed), Double(counter), Double(paceVal)]
 defaults.set(genericValues, forKey: distTimeKey)

  // LOADING VALUES
  let distTime = defaults.array(forKey: distTimeKey) ?? [Double]()
  guard let array = distTime, let pace = Optional.some.(array[2]) else{
    return 
 }

 let stringOP=String(pace)
```

**Errors:**
However, this is returning two errors

[image]
Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why do you think adding `()` to `distTime` would be appropriate?

Comment: please add distTime() function definiton too in question.

Comment: distTime() write whats in that

Comment: Apologies @Sweeper et. al. . This was an oversight, I have now corrected this, however, errors persist. I have no updated my post accordingly.

Comment: @George Where are you writing this code. Can you show the surrounding function's signature?

Comment: @Sweeper data is being stored on the press of one button, and loaded on the press of another. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I still haven't been able to fix this problem. The 'Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, no '[Any]'' is fixed by the remove of 'if let', however, this does not fulfil my requirements. @sanjaykmwt

Comment: I have updated the question @umairhhhs - apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there George the thing you are doing wrong is using the guard statement wrong. The guard statement is used for unwrapping the value of an optional Object.

Now lets analyze your code. The thing that is optional is when you get the array of values saved in `UserDefaults` and it is of `[Any]?`. Now to take it one step further you know that you saved your values as an Array of Doubles so you would need to cast `[Any]?` to `[Double]`. So lets do that exactly. So here would be the end code if you were to fix everything.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let distanceElapsed = 0.0
let counter = 3.0
let paceVal = 5.4
let genericValues = [Double(distanceElapsed), Double(counter), Double(paceVal)]
defaults.set(genericValues, forKey: distTimeKey)

guard let distTime = defaults.array(forKey: distTimeKey) as? [Double] else {
    // Do something if there are no values or if the values in the array were not of type Array of double in distTime
    fatalError("Something wrong")
}
if distTime.count > 2 {
    let pace = distTime[2]
    let paceAsString = String(pace)
    print(paceAsString)
}
```

So to explain the code as you can see we are using the `as?` to optional cast to `[Double]` and the `guard else` means if this value doesn't cast to `[Double]` execute the else block, if it does continue with the execution. In this case I just threw a `fatalError` but you could simply `return` from the execution.

Then your second problem is that you are trying to get the value at the second index of the array; however, you know if there is no value in the second index you would be attempting to access a value that doesn't exist. That's what the `distTime.count > 2` is for.

I hope this clarifies things better. I would highly recommend to go over the Swift Language basics. There are great examples in the Documentation that could help you improve your code.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this up, it's extremely helpful. Thanks for helping me out!